# Free busy query caldav for iCloud

Tags: icloud, caldav

```
URL -: https://pxx-caldav.icloud.com/token/calendars/
Content type -: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers -: {Depth: 1}
Method -: REPORT
Request content -: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
                  <C:free-busy-query xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
                       <C:time-range start = '20171104T120000Z' end='20171113T120000Z'/>
                  </C:free-busy-query>
```

Here, I am trying to fetch free/busy info using free-busy-query but server gives (500) Internal Server Error. When I have fetched calendars it shows ready/free busy access and supported report set has free-busy-query for calendar. I am missing something or iCloud doesn't support free/busy query?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, you are querying the calendar home (https://pxx-caldav.icloud.com/token/calendars/) and not individual calendars.
As per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.2 , it is not mandatory for servers to support fb queries on calendar home. Of course returning a 500 does not seem like the right response.

Now if what you want to do is to query the overall availability of the user, you should use instead the CalDAV Scheduling freebusy query. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#section-5

Comment: If I hit https://pxx-caldav.icloud.com/token/calendars/calendarId then also it gives 500 error.

Comment: While fetching calendars I ask for supported report set and it returns <free busy query> as report set i.e it supports free busy query, isn't it?

Comment: It should yes. Noticed some space around your start parameter but I do not know if it really matters. In any case, using the scheduling report might make sense.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a typo mistake. see ques.

Comment: @ArnaudQuillaud can you please check this question [caldav response  500 server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312856/caldav-yahoo-report-free-busy-query-resulting-in-500-server-error)

Comment: @PriyankKotiyal I am sending everything right in request but, still I am getting 500 response code